# Some meetings give absolutely no indication

Tags: microsoft-teams

In Microsoft Teams, some meetings ding and flash when they start like a train arriving at the station.  There is no way to miss it.  Others give absolutely no visual or audible indication and I miss all of those meetings.  This is very frustrating.

How do I fix this?

Comment: When you refer to dinging, are you talking about the notification that Teams gives where you can click join and whatever the other option is?

Comment: yes that is what i mean

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is the same as mine was. The meetings that are showing the notifications are meetings that were created with the calendar in Microsoft Teams, or had the *Teams Meeting* setting toggled on.

The meetings that are not showing notifications, are meetings that were made in the Outlook application, but did not have the *Teams Meeting* setting toggled.

Whoever has meetings that are not showing notifications, needs to update them to become Teams meetings.

Once they are converted, they will start showing the notifications on your desktop.

[image]